# Why Huge Join Fails After Specific Table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a huge select query where i have to join more than 85 tables. I keep getting an error when running the query, if I re-run the query when shrinking the overall statement it runs fine.

See a portion of the join below, it does that all the way to table 85:

```
select $imploded_tables from $apps a 
left join $mobile_c0 $m_c0 on $apps.id = $m_c0.id
left join $mobile_c1 $m_c1 on $m_c0.id = $m_c1.id
left join $mobile_c2 $m_c2 on $m_c1.id = $m_c2.id
left join $mobile_c3 $m_c3 on $m_c2.id = $m_c3.id
left join $mobile_c4 $m_c4 on $m_c3.id = $m_c4.id
left join $mobile_c5 $m_c5 on $m_c4.id = $m_c5.id
left join $mobile_c6 $m_c6 on $m_c5.id = $m_c6.id
left join $mobile_c7 $m_c7 on $m_c6.id = $m_c7.id
left join $mobile_c8 $m_c8 on $m_c7.id = $m_c8.id
left join $mobile_c9 $m_c9 on $m_c8.id = $m_c9.id
left join $mobile_c10 $m_c10 on $m_c9.id = $m_c10.id
... 
...
```

Comment: *"I keep getting an error when running the query"* <- if only there was some kind of **message** that went along with that error

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: looks like a terrible structure in the first place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mysql Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/joins-limits.html)

> The maximum number of tables that can be referenced in a single join is 61.

Answer (score 0):

As per @sf_admin answer the maximum no of join is 61 , so you can do something like below

```
select imploded_tables from apps a 
JOIN
(
SELECT * from mobile_c0 
UNION
SELECT * from mobile_c1 
....
)tmp
where(tmp.id=a.id)
```

It might not 100% percent answer your question but this is some work around I did